# Can I use UIGraphicsImageRenderer with WatchKit on watchOS 3?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, watchkit, ios10, watchos-3

When I try to use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` in a watchOS app, the compiler throws an error. The [entry in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uigraphicsimagerenderer) looks like it is only available in iOS and tvOS. Do you know why that would be the case?

```
import WatchKit

struct ImageGenerator() {
  func image() -> UIImage {
    let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat() // ERROR
    format.scale = 1
    format.opaque = true

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size, format: format) // ERROR
    let image = renderer.image { imageRendererContext in
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but I think UIImageEffects uses Quartz which is not available on the watch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIGraphicsImageRenderer` is not available on watchOS. However, you can still use legacy render API on watchOS:

```
func image() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourImageSize, isOpaque, scale)
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! 

    // draw your image at here...

    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()! // get image
}
```